# How do I change the color of a .PNG picture file?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I am making a 2D game called 'Popper' in Unity, and I have a red balloon .png file picture I want to appear on the screen, I don't just want RED balloons though, I want different colors.

Is there a easier way then making different colored picture files? If I have to use different picture files, how would I make them appear randomly on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a White balloon png. They are easiest To change color on. I find it always better to change color in  unity than to create An image for every color. It is more convenient and saves application space.

Then in your script use this.

```c#
void Start()
{
     var rnd = Random.Range(0, 6);
     switch (rnd)
     {
         case(1):
         GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.Red;
         break;

         case(2):
         // Etc. 
         break;


     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I will test this out, thank you.

Comment: It seems I came across an error when using 'Switch (rnd)'. It gave me an error of unexpected symbol?

Comment: Yes that's is because switch, case and break should be lowercase. As i said typing from mobile is hard :p. I edited the code. Also a semicolon was missing

Comment: Hey again, sorry to bother, I set that into my code and the only error given now is the GetComponent. It cannot find anything named 'image' or what I set it to. 'balloon' Is there something specific I have to set it to?

Comment: Assets/ballooncolor.cs(14,34): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `balloonred' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: Use my code and add this to the top of your CS file:

using UnityEngine.UI;